# Is there any way to show X in Wordpress page?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem showing a button (or a div or a file) in the main wordpress page, actually I want to create a live chat for wordpress site.
My code works good for me but in other sites, it is different.

```
if(!strpos($cURL,$adminp) && !strpos($cURL,$loginp) && !is_admin()){
    include_once 'sitePage/index.php';
    include_once 'model/currentV.php';
}
```

Do you have any idea how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to include those files with plugin_dir_url or get_template_directory functions.

Also use add_action(‘wp_footer’ , function(){write your code here}):

Comment: Thanks, but it is behind the content of site.

Comment: And should I include my file in wp_footer function or something else?